# Google Play Upload Key Reset

Tags: android, google-play

I lost my Google Play upload key.  I notified Google Play support and they created a new upload key for me.  They sent me the new upload certificate "fingerprints".  I do not know what to do with these fingerprints.  How do I create the upload key?